# Qt Embedded for Linux. Keyboard layout switching many time

Tags: c++, qt, embedded

I try:

```
if(lang_toggle==0)
{
      server->closeKeyboard();
      currentKeyboardHandler =
             QKbdDriverFactory::create("TTY", "keymap=/root/ar.qmap");
      server->setKeyboardHandler(currentKeyboardHandler);
      lang_toggle = 1 ;
}
else if(lang_toggle==1)
{
      server->closeKeyboard();
      currentKeyboardHandler =
            QKbdDriverFactory::create("TTY", "keymap=/root/en.qmap");
      server->setKeyboardHandler(currentKeyboardHandler);
      lang_toggle = 0 ;
}
```

as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13239590/qt-setting-qwsserver-keymap-from-code/18083656#18083656)

it works for me, but after some toggel make segmentation fault

Comment: where does it segfault? include stacktrace

Comment: if I want to change the layout a second time, the closeKeyboard() will crash, as it's trying to delete the driver defined by QWS_KEYBOARD, and it has already been deleted the first time.

Comment: QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::unlock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
Segmentation fault
QWSLock::down: Invalid argument
QWSLock::down: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument
QWSLock::lock: Invalid argument