# Qt Embedded Linux. Tool kmap2qmap not found

Tags: qt, embedded-linux

I'm trying to change the keyboard layout using the thread
[Qt Embedded for Linux. Keyboard layout switching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669464/qt-embedded-for-linux-keyboard-layout-switching) but the kmap2qmap doesn't work. bash says that that command is not found.

What package should I install to use kmap2qmap? or Where is the source path for that tool? (maybe I have it not included in the PATH variable)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a tool part of Qt, and it doesn't seem to have been packaged by binary Linux distributions because it is a tool specific to the embedded Linux variant of Qt. Therefore, you probably have to build Qt to get access to this tool. But most likely, if you're doing embedded Linux development, there is already a tool that builds Qt for you.

Comment: I have installed the Linux Console Tools, but the problem is not solved. Have someone ever used this "kmap2qmap" command??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

A small addition, on my Qt installation I ran "MaintenanceTool" and used it to install the Qt sources. If you do that you will find the sources under

`Qt/5.6/Src/qttools/src/kmap2qmap`

Qt being the Qt folder, there you can run qmake, make and it will install 'kmap2qmap' under:

`Qt/5.6/Src/qttools/bin/kmap2qmap`

`~/Qt$ ./5.6/Src/qttools/bin/kmap2qmap /tmp/keymaps/i386/azerty/azerty.map 
Usage: kmap2qmap [--header] <kmap> [<additional kmaps> ...] <qmap>
  --header   can be used to generate Qt's default compiled in qmap.`